# Application_BeginRequest doesn't work on UserControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, user-controls

I'm trying to check if the UserControl exist or not before load it.
For classic page Application_BeginRequest work, but before a usercontrol is called, this event is not fired.

Do you have any  idea how can i do it ?

ASP.NET WEBFORM 4.5

Thanks.

Comment: "if the UserControl exist or not before load it" is unclear.

Comment: Hello,I need to do a File.Exist on it before it's loaded then if it exist load it, else load a default UserControl.

Comment: Still unclear. &nbsp;

Comment: What can't you understand when i say i want to check the existance of the usercontrol ascx before loading it ?

Comment: You can do a loadusercontrol and if the physical file doesnt exist. It wont work